# Проблемы при запуске бота для Discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Код я решил взять для первого раза из документации discord.py

```
    import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

bot.run('Токен я не дам :)')
```

При запуске вылезает такая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Напишите вот так `from time import time` и все буде хорошо)

Comment: Всё тоже самое. Ничего не получилось